# Azure B2C custom IEF Profile not saving displayName when created from givenName and surname

Tags: jwt, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We have a problem we are trying to resolve today. Hopefully someone with more experience can point us in the right direction.

We have a custom policy that creates the display name from the givenName and surname fields in a custom ief policy. But name (name) is not persisting to the user object even though it exists in the name claim.

We can see with https://jwt.ms that the claim for name getting properly generated.

```
  "givenName": "John",
  "surname": "Doe",
  "name": "John Doe",
```

But the user account in Entra (AAD) is getting stored as "unknown" and here is nothing in the policy that is setting a user to "unknown".

When this was set as display input field it was getting persisted.

I'm still trying to look at the documentation, but I am not sure what else to debug since the claim exists with the correct value when checking the jwt and claims.

Edit:
This is how I have displayName defined in the policy.

```
<ClaimType Id="displayName">
    <DisplayName>Display Name</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="name" />
    </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
    <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
</ClaimType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is set to "unknown" because the user does not have a display name.

The field in the custom policy is "displayName".

You could use a transformation to copy "name" to "displayName".

Comment: Checking this. displayName isn't mapped to the 'name' claim in AAD?

Comment: I edited my question with how displayName is mapped to name.

Comment: Thank you. That was the exact help I needed. I was mapping it to 'name' instead of 'displayName'. I was thinking AD display name in the app. Working now.

Comment: My app is a Blazor app. I also need the name claim. Having problems adding it at the moment.

Comment: "name" is not a B2C attribute - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes

Comment: If you want to output the field as "name", use PartnerClaimType="name".